# Запретить повторную отправку формы

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

На странице имеется форма добавления информации о себе, которая отправляется на сервер Ajax'м.
При успехе на страницу возвращается alert уведомление. Если нажать снова кнопку "Отправить", эта форма повторно добавится в БД и так далее.
Что можно в этом случае сделать?

Comment: Важность дисаблить кнопку в том, что юзер не нажмет на нее больше одного раза, даже если это вышло случайно. С точки зрения UX кнопок с дизаблем не должно быть быть. Так что попробуйте пробуйте удовлетворить все свои хотелки и юзера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От хороших идей к худшим:

- скрыть форму;
- выполнить `rese`t для формы;
- установить `disabled = true` для кнопки `type="send"` после отправки, и в случае ошибки `disabled = false`;
- установить `disabled = true` для кнопки `type="send"` после успешного получения ответа;
- проверять дублирование данных.

Но идеально будет дисаблить кнопку после нажатия, если возникнит ошибка раздисаблить, если успешно, скрыть форму и показать типа "спасибо" или что вы там в алерте выводите.

Comment: Проверку на дублирование любые манипуляции с UI не отменяют ИМХО. Мало ли что пользователь намудрит. Любой, у кого есть мозг и кто может нажать на F12 в хроме, сможет заново включить кнопку.

Answer (score 2):

На выбор:

1. После нажатия на кнопку "отправить" блокировать ее до получения ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНОГО ответа от сервака или редактирования формы.
2. После успешной отправки очищать форму.
3. После отправки переводить форму из состояния create в состояние update.
4. Проверять дубликаты в бд при добавлении.
5. Редиректить на страницу просмотра добавленной записи, а уже там выдавать сообщение.

Есть еще пара способов, типа передавать уникальный код транзакции, чтобы наверняка определить отправку одних и тех же данных, но они сложнее в реализации.